# Set default value for string prompt

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin

The editor class has a method called GetString which prompts the user for a string value via AutoCAD's command prompt. I call it in this wrapper method:

```
public static string PromptUserForString(string message = "Enter a string: ", string defaultAnswer = "")
{
    return _editor.GetString("\n" + message).StringResult;
}
```

The argument message becomes the message the user sees when prompted for a string. How do I set it up so that the value of default answer is automatically set to be the answer so that if the user hits enter right away that becomes the value like in the screen shot below

[image]

So 1 is automatically typed as an answer meaning the user can either hit enter for the value of 1 or change 1 to whatever non-default answer they want

Comment: Do you know if there's a good API reference? I was wanting to see what all the properties were on the `PromptResult` class and if there are any overloads for `GetString`, but all I can find is a [simple example](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-203F2756-1BA6-4226-A505-B776ED8AF0FB). It looks like the Javascript API has some properties on [PromptStringOptions](http://app.autocad360.com/jsapi/v2/docs/Acad_PromptStringOptions@messageAndKeywords.html) that might let you work with default values, I was wondering if there was a parallel in .NET.

Comment: The PromptStringOptions is definitely what you're looking for.  Here's an introductory guide tot he API: http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-3cf7.htm,topicNumber=d0e30666

Comment: Sorry, here's the correct link: http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-3cf7.htm,topicNumber=d0e30666

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I paste you some code as example for the different prompts :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;

namespace EditorUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prompts with the active document ( MdiActiveDocument )
    /// </summary>
    public class EditorHelper : IEditorHelper
    {
        private readonly Editor _editor;

        public EditorHelper(Document document)
        {
            _editor = document.Editor;
        }

        public PromptEntityResult PromptForObject(string promptMessage, Type allowedType, bool exactMatchOfAllowedType)
        {
            var polyOptions = new PromptEntityOptions(promptMessage);
            polyOptions.SetRejectMessage("Entity is not of type " + allowedType);
            polyOptions.AddAllowedClass(allowedType, exactMatchOfAllowedType);
            var polyResult = _editor.GetEntity(polyOptions);
            return polyResult;
        }

        public PromptPointResult PromptForPoint(string promptMessage, bool useDashedLine = false, bool useBasePoint = false, Point3d basePoint = new Point3d(),bool allowNone = true)
        {
            var pointOptions = new PromptPointOptions(promptMessage);
            if (useBasePoint)
            {
                pointOptions.UseBasePoint = true;
                pointOptions.BasePoint = basePoint;
                pointOptions.AllowNone = allowNone;
            }

            if (useDashedLine)
            {
                pointOptions.UseDashedLine = true;
            }
            var pointResult = _editor.GetPoint(pointOptions);
            return pointResult;
        }

        public PromptPointResult PromptForPoint(PromptPointOptions promptPointOptions)
        {
            return _editor.GetPoint(promptPointOptions);
        }

        public PromptDoubleResult PromptForDouble(string promptMessage, double defaultValue = 0.0)
        {
            var doubleOptions = new PromptDoubleOptions(promptMessage);
            if (Math.Abs(defaultValue - 0.0) > Double.Epsilon)
            {
                doubleOptions.UseDefaultValue = true;
                doubleOptions.DefaultValue = defaultValue;
            }
            var promptDoubleResult = _editor.GetDouble(doubleOptions);
            return promptDoubleResult;
        }

        public PromptIntegerResult PromptForInteger(string promptMessage)
        {
            var promptIntResult = _editor.GetInteger(promptMessage);
            return promptIntResult;
        }

        public PromptResult PromptForKeywordSelection(
            string promptMessage, IEnumerable<string> keywords, bool allowNone, string defaultKeyword = "")
        {
            var promptKeywordOptions = new PromptKeywordOptions(promptMessage) { AllowNone = allowNone };
            foreach (var keyword in keywords)
            {
                promptKeywordOptions.Keywords.Add(keyword);
            }
            if (defaultKeyword != "")
            {
                promptKeywordOptions.Keywords.Default = defaultKeyword;
            }
            var keywordResult = _editor.GetKeywords(promptKeywordOptions);
            return keywordResult;
        }

        public Point3dCollection PromptForRectangle(out PromptStatus status, string promptMessage)
        {
            var resultRectanglePointCollection = new Point3dCollection();
            var viewCornerPointResult = PromptForPoint(promptMessage);
            var pointPromptStatus = viewCornerPointResult.Status;
            if (viewCornerPointResult.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
            {
                var rectangleJig = new RectangleJig(viewCornerPointResult.Value);
                var jigResult = _editor.Drag(rectangleJig);
                if (jigResult.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
                {
                    // remove duplicate point at the end of the rectangle
                    var polyline = rectangleJig.Polyline;
                    var viewPolylinePoints = GeometryUtility.GetPointsFromPolyline(polyline);
                    if (viewPolylinePoints.Count == 5)
                    {
                        viewPolylinePoints.RemoveAt(4); // dont know why but true, probably mirror point with the last point
                    }
                }
                pointPromptStatus = jigResult.Status;
            }
            status = pointPromptStatus;
            return resultRectanglePointCollection;
        }

        public PromptSelectionResult PromptForSelection(string promptMessage = null, SelectionFilter filter = null)
        {
            var selectionOptions = new PromptSelectionOptions { MessageForAdding = promptMessage };
            var selectionResult = String.IsNullOrEmpty(promptMessage) ? _editor.SelectAll(filter) : _editor.GetSelection(selectionOptions, filter);
            return selectionResult;
        }

        public PromptSelectionResult PromptForSelection(PromptSelectionOptions promptSelectionOptions,SelectionFilter filter = null)
        {
            return _editor.GetSelection(promptSelectionOptions, filter);
        }

        public void WriteMessage(string message)
        {
            _editor.WriteMessage(message);
        }

        public void DrawVector(Point3d from, Point3d to, int color, bool drawHighlighted)
        {
            _editor.DrawVector(from, to, color, drawHighlighted);
        }
    }
}
```